# Question about dictionary items addition in Python (Guess the word game)

Tags: python

How can i add a letter multiple times in the different keys of a dictionary?
I made a guess the word game where the user enters the letter to complete the mysterious word.
Everything works fine with words where letters appears just one time (Ex. Dog) but I have problems when letters occur multiple times (Ex. Employee) because only the first one is filled.

I know this is probably not the most efficient way of doing this but I'm starting programming in python and was experimenting a bit with the concepts learned.

Here's the code, thanks for the help:

```
import os

word = input('choose the word to play with: ')
os.system('cls')

word_list = list(word)
word_dict = {}

for x in range(len(word_list)):
    word_dict[str(x)] = word_list[x]


guess_dict = {}

for x in range(len(word_list)):
    guess_dict[str(x)] = '_'


health = 10

victory = False

values = list(guess_dict.values())
print(values)

while victory == False:

    letter = input('Choose the letter: ')
    if letter in word_dict.values():
        guess_dict[list(word_dict.keys())[list(word_dict.values()).index(letter)]] = letter
        valori = list(guess_dict.values())
        print(valori)
        print()
        if guess_dict == word_dict:
            victory = True
            print ('You won')
    else:
        health -= 1
        print('ERROR!! ' + str(health) + ' lives remaining')
        if health == 0:
            print('You lose')
            break
```

Comment: You cannot have duplicate keys in a dictionary if that is what you are asking. In general if you find yourself using code like `for x in range(len(word_list)): word_dict[str(x)]` you should use a list instead because you are practically using indices as keys. In your particular case you can work directly with strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is exactly the dictionary. The dictionary has only one entry for each key. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

In my opinion, you should use either a list, or a list of dictionaries.

```
import os

word = input('choose the word to play with: ')
os.system('cls')

word_list = list(word)
guess_list = [{'character': x, 'guessed': False} for x in word]


health = 10
victory = False


while True:
    str = ''
    for item in guess_list: #generate the string each iteration once
        if False == item['guessed']:
            str = str + "'_'"
        else:
            str = str + "'" + item['character'] + "'"
    print(str)

    if True == victory: #put the test here, so that the result is printed
        print('You won!')
        break

    else:
        letter = input('Choose the letter: ')
        hit = False
        missed_cnt = 0
        for item in guess_list:
            if item['character'] == letter: #if letter guessed, set flag
                item['guessed'] = True
                hit = True

            if item['guessed'] == False:    #count unguessed letters
                    missed_cnt +=1

        if False == hit:
            health -= 1
            print('ERROR!! {0} lives remaining'.format(health))

            if 0 == health:
                print('You lose!')
                break

        if 0 == missed_cnt: #exit only after printing result
            victory = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use a list of letters:

```
import os
from copy import deepcopy

word = list(input('choose the word to play with: '))
compare = deepcopy(word)
os.system('cls')

guess = []
for index, letter in enumerate(word):
    guess.append('_')

health = 10
victory = False

while not victory:

    letter = input('Choose the letter: ')
    if letter in compare:
        guess[compare.index(letter)] = letter
        compare[compare.index(letter)] = ' '
        print(guess)
        print()
        if guess == word:
            victory = True
            print ('You won')
    else:
        health -= 1
        print('ERROR!! ' + str(health) + ' lives remaining')
        if health == 0:
            print('You lose')
            break
```

The `deepcopy` in the beginning is because in Python if you do `compare = word`, `compare` would become a pointer to `word`. The variable `compare` by the way is to remove the already guessed characters from.

You could also check the input letter to make the code more robust:

```
while not victory:

    letter = input('Choose the letter: ')

    try:
        value = float(letter)
        print('Please enter a letter of type (str).')
        continue
    except ValueError:
        pass

    if len(letter) != 1:
        print('Please enter only one letter!')
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a dictionary, you could use a set().  Since guessing a letter reveals  all instances of that letter, removing it from the set corresponds to the same notion.

So you could do something like this:

```
word = input("hidden word:")
remainingLetters = set(word)

health = 10
while True:
    print( "".join( "_" if letter in remainingLetters else letter for letter in word) )
    letter = input("guess a letter:")
    if letter in remainingLetters:
        remainingLetters.remove(letter)
        if remainingLetters: continue
        print("you Win!")
        break
    health -= 1
    if health == 0:
        print("You lose")
        break
    print('ERROR!! {0} lives remaining'.format(health))
```